# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - Slider

Tags: jquery, slider

For the given website: http://whitesandsvacationhomes.com/

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.
```

I didn't program this site, but the slider wasn't responsive previously. I can get the code to work on `JSFiddle`:

```
<ul class="rslides">
        <li><img src="http://whitesandsvacationhomes.com/wp-content/themes/whitesands/img/slide-001.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://whitesandsvacationhomes.com/wp-content/themes/whitesands/img/slide-003.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://whitesandsvacationhomes.com/wp-content/themes/whitesands/img/slide-004.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://whitesandsvacationhomes.com/wp-content/themes/whitesands/img/slide-005.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Css

```
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
});
```

But for some reason, when it is uploaded to the live site, it gives me the undefined error. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is being caused by this line (27):

```
$(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
});
```

At this point in your code, jQuery is running in [no conflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). This means it has renounced use of the dollar variable. AFAIK, this happens on most (all?) WordPress sites.

To solve this you can either change any occurence of `$` to `jQuery`:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
});
```

Or, pass in a reference to the dollar variable as a parameter to the anonymous function. Within the anonymous function, you can then use $ as normal:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
});
```

This will make your slider work.

**Edit**: As Johannes says, you are including jQuery twice on the page. This is not ideal, as one version will overwrite the next and break things in unexpected ways.

Comment: Okay. I moved the function below the line of php that calls the second jQuery, and also removed the duplicate. But I am still having the same issue. Thank you, @Jack Zeling. 

`code`
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined responsiveslides.min.js:8 
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
whitesandsvacationhomes.com/:25

Comment: The trouble is now this line in holocene.js on line 117: `$('#slider1').anythingSlider({` There is no element with the id of "slider1" on the page. Plus, for me, the slider now slides and is responsive (Chrome latest on Linux Mint). Wasn't that what you were trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

most errors are

1. more then one jQuery Lib
2. Plugin-Script executes before jQuery Lib
3. jQuery and other Libs like Prototype
4. ...

your page includes 2 jQuery Libs

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: For me it was the first option: more then one jQuery Lib. Search for the JQuery "<script" source tag in your files, you will probably find more than one library include.